# "The specified Type must be a struct containing no references" using TeaFiles.NET

Tags: c#, exception, memory-mapped-files

I found this compelling library called TeaFiles.NET.

I am writing a very simple console app to test it.

Here's the code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting....");

            string filename = String.Format("History_{0}.{1}.{2}.tea",
                                               DateTime.Now.Year,
                                               DateTime.Now.Month,
                                               DateTime.Now.Day);

            File.Delete(filename);
            using (var tf = TeaFile<HistoryRow>.Create(filename))
            {
                var items = new List<HistoryRow>();

                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 100000; k++)
                    {
                        items.Add(new HistoryRow()
                        {
                            Flags = 192,
                            Name = "Name_" + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                            Value = k,
                            Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddTicks((long)i)
                        });
                    }
                }

                var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                Console.WriteLine("Initiate write...");
                tf.Write(items);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("...completed write in {0} ms.", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

    struct HistoryRow
    {
        public string Name;
        public dynamic Value;
        public Time Timestamp; 
        public int Flags;
    }
```

This should be pretty straightforward. Instead it errors at the Create() call with the following error:

**`"The specified Type must be a struct containing no references".`**

I really don't know where to even begin troubleshooting....

Comment: Perhaps the specified type needs to be a `struct` containing no references.  The only thing that is a value type in `HistoryRow` is `public int Flags`.

Comment: `Time` is a blittable struct, so the problem is `string Name` and `dynamic Value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeaFiles provide fast read/write access to time series data.  Given that the library requires a `struct` containing what @dtb describes as [blittable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx), this should work:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
struct HistoryRow
{
    public char[16] Name;
    public double Value;
    public Time Timestamp; 
    public int Flags;
}
```

Note that when storing time data series, you generally wouldn't store a description with a value, the value being one of many values in a column that already has a name.

Comment: To get a fixed array in C#, you'll need the fixed operator: `public fixed char Name[16];` and mark the struct as fixed, etc. Hopefully Cos can avoid storing this information.

Comment: @Fls'Zen: I added an attribute which should suffice.

Comment: Thank you so much @Robert Harvey  and Fls'Zen... and yes, of course I won't need the "Name"field for the actual implementation. Really appreciated.